# Requested unknown parameter 'ASSET_NAME' for row 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to create a datatable from AJAX but still getting error

> Requested unknown parameter 'ASSET_NAME' for row 0.

even if the JSON is well formatted (validated by http://www.jslint.com/) and list of columns is same as refered columns in JSON source:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#auditResults').dataTable( {
         "aaData": '[{"ASSET_NAME":"CVCMAgent","a1_hostname":"czcholsint1027.prg-dc.dhl.com","a1_port":"5000","a1_asset_version":"1.6","a1_build":"1504130525"},
          {"ASSET_NAME":"CVCMAgent","a1_hostname":"czcholsint1027.prg-dc.dhl.com","a1_port":"6000","a1_asset_version":"1.6","a1_build":"1504130525"}]',
          "aoColumns": [
            {"sTitle": "ASSET_NAME", "mData": "ASSET_NAME"} ,  {"sTitle": "a1_hostname", "mData": "a1_hostname"} ,  {"sTitle": "a1_port", "mData": "a1_port"} ,  {"sTitle": "a1_asset_version", "mData": "a1_asset_version"} ,  {"sTitle": "a1_build", "mData": "a1_build"}  
             ]
     } );
 } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="auditResults" name="auditResults" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     
       <th>ASSET_NAME</th>
     
       <th>a1_hostname</th>
     
       <th>a1_port</th>
     
       <th>a1_asset_version</th>
     
       <th>a1_build</th>
         </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I have tried many combinations but without any success.

What is going wrong there?

Thanks
Reddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the JSON as a string, you should pass it as JSON :

```
"aaData": [{"ASSET_NAME":"CVCMAgent","a1_hostname":"czcholsint1027.prg-dc.dhl.com","a1_port":"5000","a1_asset_version":"1.6","a1_build":"1504130525"},{"ASSET_NAME":"CVCMAgent","a1_hostname":"czcholsint1027.prg-dc.dhl.com","a1_port":"6000","a1_asset_version":"1.6","a1_build":"1504130525"}]',
```

if you for whatever reason not are able to do that, you can use `JSON.parse()` :

```
"aaData": JSON.parse('[{"ASSET_NAME":"CVCMAgent","a1_hostname":"czcholsint1027.prgdc.dhl.com","a1_port":"5000","a1_asset_version":"1.6","a1_build":"1504130525"},          {"ASSET_NAME":"CVCMAgent","a1_hostname":"czcholsint1027.prgdc.dhl.com","a1_port":"6000","a1_asset_version":"1.6","a1_build":"1504130525"}]'),
```

see -> http://jsfiddle.net/7ng9wfak/412/

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew that I overlooked something simple :) Thank you again!